# Yii2: How to put null values to the end of an object list when sorting is ascending?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

Here is my DataProvider:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query'      => $query,
    'pagination' => ['pageSize' => 50],
    'sort'       => [
        'defaultOrder' => [
            'priority'      => SORT_DESC,
            'date_targeted' => SORT_ASC
        ]
     ]
]);
```

[image]

[image]
[image]
What I want is to move ("not set") to the end of the results.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please specify what DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add new field in `select`. And set in `IF` case like that:

```php
$query->select([
    '*', 
    new \yii\db\Expression('IF(date_targeted IS NULL, 1, 0) AS date_targeted_flag')
]);
```

And in `sort` add `date_targeted_flag`:

```php
'sort' => [
    'defaultOrder' => [
        'date_targeted_flag' => SORT_ASC,
        'priority'           => SORT_DESC,
        'date_targeted'      => SORT_ASC
    ],
    'attributes' => [
        'date_targeted_flag',
        'priority',
        'date_targeted'
    ]
]
```

This works fine - [here](https://yadi.sk/i/Mvn_ZMctfJJXY) and [here](https://yadi.sk/i/yW7HzKChfJJYF).

Comment: @ChhornSoro I don't know. vitalik_74 provided this answer.

Comment: @vitalik_74 The error gone but the "not set" is still at the top of the result.

Comment: I changed `IF` to `date_targeted IS NULL`. And update my answer and screenshots. I forgot you use in `DATE` field `NULL` value. It is value check with operator `IS`.